# Calling a Bootstrap modal dialog from xp:button and pass a scoped variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I have a button (code below) that sits in a repeat control. When I click the button it sets  viewScope.vsRLinkKey with a value from the viewEntry of the repeat and calls the bootstrap modal. The button needs to be set to norefresh because with a full refresh the Modal flashes on the screen, on a partial refresh the screen greys out but the modal does not appear. In my modal I set a computed field to display the vontens of viewScope.vsRLinkKey and it is always null. USing the Debug ToolBar I can see that the value of vsRLinkKey is set correctly but the modal does not pick up the value. So I believe that I have either a refresh issue or a scope issue, but in either case I need to pass the value of the field to the modal. None of my efforts have worked so far. 
The question is how can I pass a context variable to the bootstrap modal control?

```
<xp:button value="Respond" id="button3" styleClass="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                        <xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-target" value="#respModal">
                            </xp:attr>

                        </xp:this.attrs>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="norefresh">
                            <xp:this.action>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsRLinkKey = reqEntry.getColumnValue("rLinkKey")}]]>
                            </xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>
```

Comment: Bill, are you using xe:dialog for your Bootstrap dialog?

Comment: No using the bs dialog guess could solve it by using xe:dialog